# Handle resource with ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest

My app suppose to download file from DB.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadBook(@PathVariable Long id) {

Book book = bookService.findById(id);

return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + book.getFileName() + ".pdf\"")
        .body(new ByteArrayResource(book.getFile()));

}
```

This works when i call it directly from browser (**download pop up**), but what i'm tring to do is handle it with ajax call. This is my ajax method so far, but this code actually just alert me with success **with no dowload pop up.**

```
downloadBook : function(bookId) {
    $.ajax({
        url : basePath + '/book/download/' + bookId,
        success : function() {
            alert("success!");
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("error!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
downloadBook : function(bookId) {
    window.location = basePath + '/book/download/' + bookId
}
```

My downloadBook method looks like this now and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

See [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

What's happening here is that your ajax request is being made to `/book/download/` as specified in the `url:` parameter. When the request completes successfully it fires the `success` callback. However, all you are doing there is showing an alert - with `alert("success!")` - so nothing further will happen.

The linked answer explains why you cannot simply do this with ajax like you might imagine. I haven't reiterated all of the linked answer as it's already been explained there, but the principal of that answer is exactly the same for your problem.